# How to print frequency of characters in java

Tags: java, arrays, frequency

I'm fairly new to Java and I want to print the frequency of characters in a string ('filtered'). I filtered the input to the point where there is only characters left that are in my 'az' array. In my mind this should work, but I'm obviously doing something wrong because I'm either getting error messages("out of range") or its just not printing the right values.

```
char [] az = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
              'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1',
              '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ' '};
int [] freq = new int [37];
char c;
for (int i=0; i<37; i++) {
  c = filtered.charAt(i);
  if (c == az[i])
    freq[c]++;
}

System.out.println("char"+"\t"+"freq");

for (int i=0; i<37; i++) {
  System.out.println("   "+i+"\t     "+freq[i]);
```

Comment: change `freq[c]++;` to `freq[i]++;`

Comment: Your logic is wrong by the way, it does not compute the frequence of characters.

Comment: filtered is a String without any special characters or capitals. I tried debugging, and it seems the number in the first for-loop is too big, which I'm still unsure of why. I also changed freq[c]++; to freq[i]++; but it didn't change the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing indexes. Here is a not optimized fix of your code.

You can see how not naming variables `c`, `i`, ... help avoiding mistakes.

```
char[] az = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
        'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1',
        '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ' '};
int[] freq = new int[az.length];
for(int filteredIndex = 0; filteredIndex < filtered.length(); ++filteredIndex) {
    char filteredCharacter = filtered.charAt(filteredIndex);
    for (int azIndex = 0; azIndex < az.length; azIndex++) {
        if (filteredCharacter == az[azIndex])
            freq[azIndex]++;
    }
}

System.out.println("char" + "\t" + "freq");

for (int azIndex = 0; azIndex < 37; azIndex++) {
    System.out.println("   " + az[azIndex] + "\t     " + freq[azIndex]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right, once you have too many i's and j's and c's it gets really messy. I should force myself to use your style.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the logic of your code, which was wrong, even without the thrown exception.

```
String filtered = "would you meet me at 3 in the morning";
char[] az = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
                'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w',
                'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
                '9', ' ' };
int[] freq = new int[az.length];
char c;
for (int i = 0; i < filtered.length() ; i++) {
    c = filtered.charAt(i);
    if (c == ' ')
        freq[az.length - 1]++;
    else if (Character.isAlphabetic(c))
        freq[c - 'a']++;
    else 
        freq[c - '0' + 26]++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < az.length; i++) 
    System.out.println("   " + az[i] + "\t     " + freq[i]);
```

Here is what you had wrong :

- you hardcoded the bounds of the loops, which is not a good idea
- you compared each `az[i]` with each `c = filtered.charAt(i)` but c is not necessarily at index i